# How to avoid race condition during docker overlay network creation?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have two machines HostA and HostB with consul and docker daemon properly configured so that I can use `docker network create -d overlay sharednet`

I have a `TestScript.sh` to check if a network exists and if not create the network. And this script is available on both HostA and HostB. I also have a `MasterScript.sh` only on A, which basically just invoke `TestScript.sh` on each machine. After I run my `MasterScript.sh`, I see a surprising result, two network with the same name got created!!! This is arguably a docker daemon synchronization issue.

```
[HostA]# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                 DRIVER
ad492bba9efa        sharednet            overlay
ba53d4e7b739        sharednet            overlay

[HostB]# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                 DRIVER
ad492bba9efa        sharednet            overlay
ba53d4e7b739        sharednet            overlay
```

The expected behavior is that when I created a network `testnw` on HostA, then on HostB I should see something like this

```
[HostB]# docker network ls
68994f95cd67        testnw               overlay
[HostB]# docker network create -d overlay testnw
Error response from daemon: network with name testnw already exists
```

Due to some restrictions I cannot modify the `MasterScript.sh`, but I can modify my `TestScript.sh`. So the question is, is it possible for me to resolve this race condition under this restriction?

Comment: I totally agree with your expectation; this looks like a bug. Why do you check the networks on all hosts in the first place? Wouldn't it be sufficient to do it on one host?

Comment: @morxa On each machine I have a copy of `TestScript.sh` managing local docker containers and attach them to appropriate networks. If the network is not there, the script will just create the network and attach container to the network. Since `TestScript.sh` is fully distributed in nature and by design cannot talk to each other, TestScript.sh on HostA does not know if TestScript.sh on HostB have issued the create command or not. Therefore I have to rely on docker daemon to synchronize my network create command.

Comment: Which docker version are you using?

Comment: @morxa docker 1.10.2 I installed with https://get.docker.com/ script, so I think that's the latest stable build

Comment: Interesting, now I'm seeing the same issue. Did you file a bug report?

Comment: Assuming that consul is up and running on both machines already, could you place a flag in the consul key-value store to claim a 'lock' on the creation of the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue had been reported to Docker Github, and is currently being tracked under https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20648

Answer (score 0):

This issue is still not resolved, but I was easily able to avoid it using the `run-one` command (instead of `run command`, it becames `run-one run command`, and return an error if the command is still running).

*(You can verify if the `run-one` command is available with `which run-one`)*

**Steps:**

1. Create a script that creates the network (it may accept the network name as a parameter, like `docker network create "$1"`).
2. Create the network (wherever it should be created) by calling the script with `run-one` to make sure that it is not executing twice for the same network (`run /path/to/script network-name`).
3. ?
4. Profit!

You can see this approach in action in the (demo) script below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

function error {
    msg="$(date '+%F %T') - ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}:${BASH_LINENO[0]}: ${*}"
    >&2 echo -e "${RED}${msg}${NC}"
    exit 2
}

file="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"

command="${1:-}"

if [ -z "$command" ]; then
    error "[error] no command entered"
fi

shift;

case "$command" in
    "clean")
        sudo docker network prune -f
        ;;
    "test1")
        run-one "$file" "test:concurrent" "test:network"
        ;;
    "test2")
        run-one "$file" "test:concurrent" "test:network:unique"
        ;;
    "test:concurrent")
        echo "===========before==========="
        sudo docker network ls
        echo "============================"

        cmd="$1"

        pids=()

        for i in $(seq 1 3); do
            "$file" "$cmd" &
            pids["${i}"]=$!
        done

        idx=0

        for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
            wait "$pid" && status="$?" || status="$?"
            idx=$((idx + 1))

            if [ "$status" != '0' ]; then
                echo "error in process $pid (#$idx)"
            fi
        done

        echo "===========after============"
        sudo docker network ls
        echo "============================"
        ;;
    "test:network:unique")
        run-one "$file" "test:network"
        ;;
    "test:network")
        sudo docker network create "my-network"
        ;;
    *)
        echo -e "${RED}[error] invalid command: $command${NC}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Then:

1. Run `/path/to/script clean` to remove unused networks (make sure to run this script in a development environment).
2. Run `/path/to/script test1` and see that there are 3 networks named `my-network`.
3. Run `/path/to/script clean` again.
4. Run `/path/to/script test2` and see that there is only 1 network named `my-network` (2 of the 3 processes ended up with an error due to the `run-one` command, with only one creating the network).

The fact that the script adds another abstraction layer (that may add complexity if you intend to use network options), aside from the fact that you must create the script and refer to it, makes this solution to be described at best as a workaround.

That said, this is easily achievable and I don't think this should be labeled as a hack, although a proper solution IMO should be on the docker engine side (probably in the API).

This may not be so easily achievable with `docker-compose` tough, unless you run it from a script that you can easily change and you know the names of the networks beforehand.